# add name of people to the scatterplot

Tags: python

I have a dataset of 6 people, which is called df

| People | Height | weight |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Neil | 186 | 90 |
| Olaf | 187 | 60 |
| Jake | 188 | 75 |
| Mitt | 189 | 77 |
| Gaby | 181 | 62 |
| Sam | 180 | 65 |

Now I would like to to do a scatterplot which shows the name of the people in above left of the point in the scatterplot. but i don't get the name of the people.

I did these

```
_, ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(5,5))
s = sns.scatterplot(x=df['Height'], y=df['weight'], ax=ax) 
g.set(xlabel='height', ylabel='weight')
plt.title("relationship between height and weight");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using [plotly](https://plotly.com/python/) (question does not state a certain library):

```py
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
    {
        "People": {0: "Neil", 1: "Olaf", 2: "Jake", 3: "Mitt", 4: "Gaby", 5: "Sam"},
        "Height": {0: 186, 1: 187, 2: 188, 3: 189, 4: 181, 5: 180},
        "weight": {0: 90, 1: 60, 2: 75, 3: 77, 4: 62, 5: 65},
    }
)

px.scatter(
    df,
    x="Height",
    y="weight",
    text="People",
    height=500,
    width=500,
    title="relationship between height and weight",
    labels={"Height": "height[m]"}
).update_traces(textposition="top left", textfont_size=18)
```

[image]

Comment: do you know how to set the text size?

Comment: Yes, it's in the [docs](https://plotly.com/python/reference/scatter/#scatter-textfont-size)

Comment: sorry do you now how can I change the labels of x and y, couldn't find in the doc?

Comment: What do you mean by "change"? And what docs did you search?

Comment: i want the x label instead of height  this height[m]

Comment: the docs you sent

Comment: You can find more documentation when you do [a websearch for the library name and the thing you want to do, e.g.: "plotly express scatter change label"](https://www.google.com/search?q=plotly+express+scatter+change+label). Then you can find the [documentation of `px.scatter`](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.scatter.html), which explains how to use the `labels` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you would manually add them using seaborn

```py
import seaborn as sns

# Create a dataframe with weight, height, and people data
data = {
    'weight': [68, 70, 72, 65, 58, 59, 64, 68, 69, 71],
    'height': [175, 179, 180, 166, 159, 162, 168, 172, 173, 177],
    'people': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Create a scatter plot with labels
ax = sns.scatterplot(x='weight', y='height', data=df)

# Add labels to each point
for line in range(0, df.shape[0]):
     ax.text(df.weight[line]+0.1, df.height[line], df.people[line], horizontalalignment='left', size='medium', color='black', weight='semibold')
```

[image]